# In Ubuntu 20.04 conda gives a Permission denied error

Tags: anaconda, permission-denied

One day, as my Ubuntu user, there was a problem with my installation of `conda`,

```
/home/data/userleo/anaconda3/conda/bin: Permission denied
```

Even when I gave `annaconda3` `chmod -R 777`, this problem still occurs. So I deleted `conda`, but when I reinstalled, the following problem appeared,

```
bash /home/data/userleo/anaconda3/conda.exe
PREFIX=/home/data/userleo/anaconda3
Unpacking payload ...
Anaconda3-2021.05-Linux-x86_64.sh: line 381: /home/data/userleo/anaconda3/conda.exe: Permission denied
Anaconda3-2021.05-Linux-x86_64.sh: line 383: /home/data/userleo/anaconda3/conda.exe: Permission denied


381 "$CONDA_EXEC" constructor --extract-tar --prefix "$PREFIX"

383 "$CONDA_EXEC" constructor --prefix "$PREFIX" --extract-conda-pkgs || exit 1
```

How do I get Anaconda to work without permission denied errors?

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu, as you mentioned, why is `conda` installed as `/home/data/userleo/anaconda3/conda.exe`. Usually `.exe` files are Windows executables, although technically a Linux executable could have the `.exe` extension, it would just be very confusing. You did use the Linux installer from [the Anaconda website](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual#Downloads), right?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have installed conda correctly , no idea why there is exe with ubuntu .

what you can do is to Check the cached installed earlier , the remaining files in any , and the installed files .

with `ls -ld /path/to/folder`

you will noticed that root is the owner for some files , then you can change it with `chown`